# stunnel4: Disable Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation

Tags: openssl, stunnel

How is it possible to disable Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation in stunnel4? I'm using version stunnel 4.53-1.1ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty with OpenSSL 1.0.1f and stunnel 4.53-1.1 on Debian Wheezy with OpenSSL 1.0.1e.

The [stunnel docs](https://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html) lists an option for that:

> renegotiation = yes | no
>
> support SSL renegotiation

but unfortunately, this leads to the following error:

> Line 70: "renegotiation = no": Specified option name is not valid here

But where is this the option valid? I tried it for the single services (which makes no sense anyhow), but it didn't work either. The documentation is not very verbose about this, and I couldn't find any information about this with search engines.

Has anyone a clue, how to get this right?

---

I used the following minimal configuration:

```
pid=/stunnel4.pid
debug = 5
output = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log
cert = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
key = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
renegotiation = no
[https]
accept  = 443
connect = localhost:8000
```

---

These tests showed, that Renegotiation is supported:

Qualys' ssltest shows:

> Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation: Supported   DoS DANGER (more info)

Doing it manually with openssl, also confirms:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
[...]
---
R
RENEGOTIATING
depth=0 CN = mint.home
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mint.home
verify return:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [stunnel ChangeLog](https://www.stunnel.org/sdf_ChangeLog.html), `renegotiation` parameter was added in **stunnel version 4.54**. That explains why stunnel 4.53 complains about

> Specified option name is not valid here

The alternative solutions:

1. Installing [stunnel deb file with higher version](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=stunnel) for example stunnel for jessie (testing) or for sid (unstable)
2. Doing self-compile stunnel

Comment: Can confirm that for Ubuntu (installed the deb from utopic), works as expected. On debian, two requirements are not met. Thanks :)